# http routing instead of vhost with Angular2?

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, angular2-http

I have a nodeJS based web app and I want to have a blog subdomain. This is a static (Hexo Based) blog. So I am currently serving my blog on `http://localhost:4000/` and an Angular App on `http://localhost:4200/`, with a project dir like this:

```
project
  |--------Hexo Blog
  |            |------all Blog files
  |
  |--------Angular App
               |------all ng2 files
```

I suppose one approach would be to use an Express app.js and `vhost` to route the blog subdomain to a different port, a bit like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.host) {
        if (typeof req.headers.host === 'string' && req.headers.host.match(/blog\.myDomain\.com/)) { // a simple url match.
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://0.0.0.0:4000/' }); // hexo is running on this host and you can change it.
        } else {
            next(); // pass the request to other app.
        }
    }
});
```

However, I'd rather not add express and vhost as a dependency if it's not required. Is this something I could do with Angular?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to serve the static content as routes in the angular2 app?

Comment: or is it just about directing the traffic towards the static blog or the app based on the accessed subdomain?

Comment: @toskv the latter I think

Comment: then I think you'll have to do it on the server. once you've reached the angular app it's already too late. :)

Comment: @toskv OK, so I do need express then

Comment: that's the way to go.